# Multiple modal components with Vue

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, vue-component

I am having trouble implementing dynamic modal component in Vue.

A common approach I follow to display a set of data fetched from the db is I dump each of the rows in an HTML table element by iterating over each of the row of the db result. Something like this: [image]

As you can see in the screenshot, each of the rows has one or more buttons which are dynamically generated by the loop.
In order to bind a modal component to each of the buttons (say the Remove buttons in this scenario) I do something like this.
**HTML:**

```
<div id="app">
    <?php foreach($result as $x): ?>
        <modal v-if="showModal">I am Modal $x</modal>
        <btn @trigger="onShowModal">Button $x</btn>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

So if I have three rows in my result, the aforementioned block of code will take the shape of something like this:

```
<div id="app">
        <modal v-if="showModal">I am Modal 1</modal>
        <btn @trigger="onShowModal">Button 1</btn>

        <modal v-if="showModal">I am Modal 2</modal>
        <btn @trigger="onShowModal">Button 2</btn>

        <modal v-if="showModal">I am Modal 3</modal>
        <btn @trigger="onShowModal">Button 3</btn>
</div>
```

And here is what I do in the JavaScript end:

**JavaScript:**

```
    Vue.component('btn',{
      template: `<button @click="$emit('trigger')"><slot></slot></button>`,
    });

    Vue.component('modal',{
      template: `<p><slot></slot></p>`,
    });

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        showModal: false
      },
      methods: {
        onShowModal(){
          this.showModal = true;
        }
      }
    });
```

The problem with this approach is, when I click any one of the Remove buttons, I get a 'stack' of modals instead of the modal I wanted to view. And that's because I am setting `showModal` to `true` and if you see the populated HTML block you will see that each of the modals is set to `v-if="showModal"`.

[Click here to see a demo](http://jsbin.com/vikilepela/edit?html,output)

And as I am beginning to understand frontend-backend relationship, I am learning that this pattern is appearing more frequently in an application. How do I fix this issue (with a very vue-beginner-friendly level)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The root issue is that you are referencing the same data property `showModal` on all of the modal components.

You could make another component to encapsulate the button and modal component pair. This way there is a separate `showModal` data property for each `modal` and `btn` pair:

```js
Vue.component('btn',{
  template: `<button @click="$emit('trigger')"><slot></slot></button>`,
});

Vue.component('modal',{
  template: `<p><slot></slot></p>`,
});

Vue.component('modal-btn', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <modal v-if="showModal">
        <slot>I am a modal</slot>
      </modal>
      <btn @trigger="showModal = true">Show Modal</btn>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return { showModal: false }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showModal: false
  },
  methods: {
    onShowModal(){
      this.showModal = true;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <modal-btn></modal-btn>
  <modal-btn>I am another modal</modal-btn>
  <modal-btn>I'm a third modal</modal-btn>
</div>
```

Comment: In the case of a `modal-button` component, what if I wanted the data property name and the function-to-execute within `@trigger` to be user provided rather than static `showModal` and `onShowModal` prop and function. I mean something like this:`<modal-button functoexec="onShowConfirmModal" modaltype="showConfirmModal"></modal-button>`?

Comment: In that case, your `@trigger` handler in the `modal-btn` component should emit an event (say `$emit('show')`), then the parent component should handle that event via `<modal-btn @show="onShowConfirmModal>`

Comment: Thanks, that takes care of the event emission. But what about the `v-if` directive in `<modal>`? how do I bind the value of v-if to a data property of user's choice say, `showConfirmModal`? I am stuck with `<modal v-if="iAmAFixedProperty">`

Comment: Not sure what you mean, why not just use the `showModal` property in the `v-if`?

Comment: thanks for this solution, I was stuck also on a similar issue and came across this @thanksd

Answer (score 3):

You might need a more data centric approach to what you are trying. Something like,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.0.3/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <template v-for="item in items">
      <modal v-if="item.show">I am a dummy Modal for {{item.name}}</modal>
      <btn @trigger="item.show = !item.show">Button for {{item.id}}</btn>
    </template>
  </div>

  <script>
    Vue.component('btn',{
      template: `<button @click="$emit('trigger')"><slot></slot></button>`,
    });

    Vue.component('modal',{
      template: `<p><slot></slot></p>`,
    });

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        items: [
          {id: 1, name: 'item 1', show: false},
          {id: 2, name: 'item 2', show: false},
          {id: 3, name: 'item 3', show: false}
        ],
        showModal: false
      },
      methods: {
        onShowModal(){
          this.showModal = true;
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You could then also get away with a single `modal` component that receives the applicable data it should display via a `prop`

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are having is that all modals are bound to one data attribute (`showModal`) so all modals will show when you set this to true. The solution is to isolate each button within it's own component which has it's own `showModal` attribute rather than emitting it to the parent:

```
Vue.component('btn',{
  template: `<div><button @click="showModal = true"><slot></slot></button>   
    <modal v-if="showModal">I am a modal for {{button}}</modal></div>`,
  props: ['button'],
  data(){
    return {
      showModal: false
    }
  }
});
```

And here's the [updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kekasaneko/edit?html,output)

If you need different modals for each button type, then simply create two button components `edit-button`, `delete-button` etc